# Load only the print data using Ajax/get

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm need to get only the print data of an html using jquery/ajax, I have

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'http://192.168.1.111/sd/interruociones/',
            type:'get',
            dataType: '',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }           
        });
```

On the console i obtain

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="zepto.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
            $('#content').load('/arduino/temperature');
        }
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setInterval(refresh, 100);">
        <span id="content">0</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I only want the data in the span tag. I change the datatype to html and txt but doesn't works, Help!

Comment: can  you change what the server returns? that would be the obvious answer. Or make another endpoint to return just the data you want? Seems like it's returning a whole html document, which is no good for an ajax call generally

Comment: try `$(response).find('span').html()` to get only html inside span from your response.

Comment: Does this above solution worked for you?